# Django and Postgres - ImproperlyConfigured Exception with psycopg2

Tags: python, django, apache, postgresql, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up a Django project using Postgres.  This is my first time with postgresql, as all my previous db backends for Django have been using MySQL.

Currently, I am getting

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: 
  dlopen(/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/geocode_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): 
    Symbol not found: _PyBytes_Type
```

when loading the server after restarting Apache.

I'm using mod_wsgi to integrate with my system's Apache server.  The project is within a virtualenvwrapper container, so the wsgi file needs to include code to execute the activation script.

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir("/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/geocode_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages")

sys.path.append("/Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/geodjango")
sys.path.append("/Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/geodjango/geodjango")

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "geodjango.settings")

exec(open("/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/geocode_env/bin/activate_this.py").read())

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I also have a virtualhosts file configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      dev.geocode.com
    ServerAlias     geocode.com
    ServerAdmin     jason@someschool.edu

    DocumentRoot    "/Users/jason/projects/geocode_django"
    Alias /static/ /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/static/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/geodjango/geodjango/wsgi.py

    <Directory /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/static >
            require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/geodjango/geodjango >
            <Files wsgi.py >
                    Require all granted
            </Files>

    </Directory>

    CustomLog /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django/logs/error.log

 </VirtualHost>
```

Since this project is running Django 1.7 and using Python 3.4, I've ensured the following:

- virtualenvwrapper was created with the command 
  `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 geocode_env --no-site-packages`
- mod_wsgi3 was installed using `brew`, and the appropriate `LoadModule` configuration was added to /etc/apache2/httpd
- WSGIPythonPath was added to httpd.conf with the values `WSGIPythonPath /Users/jason/projects/geocode_django:/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/geocode_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages`
- I've executed `touch settings.py` and `touch wsgi.py` before and after restarting Apache.
- `apachectl configtest` returns no errors
- From a python shell, I can execute `import psycopg2` with no exceptions

and yet I am still getting the ImproperlyConfigured exception above. Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: This could be related: http://bugs.python.org/issue21122

Comment: I guess your mod_wsgi is using a different python3.4 library, even though you think that is not the case.